# why does Plesk set up only one nameserver by default?

Tags: dns, plesk

When using Plesk 9.5 the default DNS template only includes one nameserver. An NS record of ns. and an a record ns. pointing to the default ip.

Two nameserves are mandatory, so why would plesk have only one in the template. Am I missing something?

I have found several hosting company guides that all explain the process of adding an extra name server to the template, that explain what I mean.

https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/727/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzAxNjkxOTczL3NpZC9EemppX3Bxaw%3D%3D

http://www.jodohost.com/plesk/Creating_Nameservers/creating_nameservers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Plesk includes only one NS in default template, because Plesk itself serves as NS server by default and second NS is supposed to be pointing at another machine (though it is commonly tricked). Unless a hosting provider configures it for you (which they are supposed to do), you can have two choices:

1. (trick) Give your Plesk server one more name (alias) and add another NS for that name. Most (if not all) DNS validation tools would consider it valid configuration. Though technically it would be the same machine for both records, it is hard to distinguish from outside
2. (proper) Set up second DNS server (i.e. slave DNS) and include it in DNS template

Comment: I actually spoke to someone from parallels about this and they said the same thing. It's frustrating as Plesk is commonly installed on customers own virtual private or dedicated servers. As the majority of people only have one server it's confusing for them. We now recommend customers use their registrars name servers, but also altered our build scripts to add NS1 and NS2.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the documentation it seems that you aren't missing anything. It seems to be an oversight on their part. I looked on their website but didn't see a place to post a bug so I am not sure how aware they are of this or how to make them aware of it.